# Getting current directory when run EXE from context menu

Tags: c#

1. I'd like to create a set of folders from context menu instead of one folder.
2. I've created a batch-script that can do that and put it in context menu.
3. I've also created a little C# console app that does the same but the problem is that the script/app can only create folders in the specific location that is manually set in the script/app. Basically speaking I can't create folders wherever I want but only in the location I set in the script/app.

Question:

Is there a way to get the current OPEN directory where the context menu is called up and pass to the console app?

I want to create a set of folders in the currently opened directory from the context menu if that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: this is what I finally came up with and exactly what I needed (although, it might be lame implementation as this is my very first console app ever but it works lol):

```
class CreateFolders
{
    public static int countItem = 0;

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {       
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory ();
            string originalPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory ();
            string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\CreateFolders\\folders.txt";
            string[] folders ={};
            string line;
            int counter = 0;

            StreamReader file = new StreamReader (filePath);

            if(new FileInfo(filePath).Length != 0)

            {
                List<string> folderNames = new List<string>();
                while ((line = file.ReadLine ()) != null)
                {
                    folderNames.Add (line);
                    counter++;
                }

                folders = folderNames.ToArray();
                int arrayLength = folders.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)

                    {
                        CreateFolder (path += "\\" + folders[i]);
                        path = originalPath;
                    }

                if (countItem != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("\nGreat! {1} folders have been created in: {0}\n", originalPath, countItem);
                }

            } else
                {
                Console.WriteLine ("File is empty. Add names of your folders\n");
                }

            Console.WriteLine ("\n");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Folders were not created :(\n");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    static void CreateFolder(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        string dirName = folder.Name;

        if (!Directory.Exists (path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory (path);
            path = " ";
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} ok", dirName);
            countItem++;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("{0} exists", dirName);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the directory where your program runs from, just do

```
var FolderPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Otherwise, to edit the Windows Context Menu:
First, create a text file and copy this code inside, replacing MyFolder and MyProgram with the path and name of your program:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\MyProgram]
@="&MyProgram"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\MyProgram\command]
@="C:\\MyFolder\\MyProgram.exe"
```

Then rename the file "SetRegistryValue.reg" and run it.
Double-click and you are good to go.
I tested it myself, the solution comes from this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/445925/how-to-add-item-to-right-click-menu-when-not-selecting-a-folder-or-file). 
[image: This is what the script does; my program name was "go.exe"]

Comment: No, I mean the current OPEN directory where I create folders.

Comment: Well, may I advise to post your code? It can help us understand better what you mean.

Comment: uploaded a screenshot that explains better

Comment: Thanks mate! I didn't realize that your the very first answer was exactly what I need :) These methods Environment.CurrentDirectory, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Environment.CurrentDirectory do exactly what I needed. Thanks again!